# How to display breakdown by quarter #DAX #Powerbidesktop

Tags: powerbi, dax

my first time in the forum, be nice;)
I got a simple model with a fact table, a dimension table and a calendar

[Model view] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/01J5R.png)

I'd like to achieve the breakdown by quarter within each year as displayed in the table below (Breakdown column):

[Desired outcome] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7m6Q.png)

I figured that, to get there, I need a measure displaying total sales within each Year (repeated for each Quarter within that year) to be used as denominator.  The values I'd like to be generated would be the ones displayed on column 3.
My Numerator would be my measure on column 2 Total Sales = SUM (Revenues [Value (USD)])

So, my question is how would i achieve a measure to get the figures on column 3?
Or alternatively, how do I get to the result displayed under the Breakdown column?

Thanks for your help

Sax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

There are two options:

```
    QuarterBreakdown (1) =
    VAR YearSales = SUMX (VALUES ('Calendar'[Year]), 
    CALCULATE ([1. Total Sales], ALLSELECTED ('Calendar')))
    RETURN
    DIVIDE ([1. Total Sales], YearSales )
```

OR

```
    QuarterBreakdown (2) = 
    VAR YearSales = 
    CALCULATE ([1. Total Sales],
    ALL('Calendar'), VALUES('Calendar'[Year]))
    RETURN
    DIVIDE ([1. Total Sales],YearSales)
```

The second measure is simpler and works better if an external filter is selected (i.e. Quarters), as it keeps the right %s:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each year sum of sales can be calculated in third column as

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM (Revenues [Value (USD)]), ALLEXCEPT(Revenues, Revenues [Year]))
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately doesn't work and don't get the desired outcome for the measure but the overall total across all years/quarters repeated:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTiDq.png

Comment: You need to use `Revenues [Year]` not `Revenues [Quarter]`

Comment: Apologies, that was just me testing.. If you put Year is exactly the same result https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lx5j.png